Linking two instances of IAR/IJet through software?
I have two boards which are communicating to one another wirelessly. Both are running firmware created in IAR. I have a difficult to trace edge case that is causing a disconnect between the two boards. I can set up and run two I-jet debuggers, but I haven't found a way to cause one I-jet to trigger both instances of firmware to pause execution in IAR so I can take a look at both sides and determine roughly where each is in its execution and at least help me decide which side of the fault to start looking at first.
My plan right now is to mod the boards to take an output into an input on each board, write a lightweight ISR I can break on, and have either board trigger a pause on both. If there's a simpler way to do this using IAR built in functionality that would be preferable though. The board that is paused remotely would not sync up perfectly because of the delay in sending the pause from one image/IAR to the other, but that's ok for now.
I have tried Google and a cursory search of the manual. I am going to dig deeper into the manual and hopefully there's something in there that addresses my issue.

This looks like an XY problem to me. Don't you have a separated communication channel to output debug traces? Or do you have at least one port pin to toggle in different styles to trace the execution? -- If you have such a complex setup, first make sure your lower levels work correctly. Then use a simulation on the PC to clean up the most mess in the higher levels. Commonly there are no issues left after that stage.

There is a function for connecting two instances of Embedded workbench. It is intended for debugging of asymmetric multiprocessor systems but it may be applicable to this case as well. I don't know the specific details but check your manual or contact IAR support.

I wanted to circle back on this - there is a section of the manual called "Multicore debugging" where an XML file can be created that references two IAR projects and allows running both projects on iJet debuggers with control from a single IAR instance.
Unfortunately, my timing constraints with this particular issue were such that using the Multicore debugging in IAR did not allow me to control the projects with the timeliness I needed to; but if anyone runs into an issue between two boards in the future I wanted to put this out there as something to start Googling for.
This feature could be a really good way to test an interface between two devices on system integration, debug serial comms, etc. Just not the issue I originally tried it for.
